# Residual Plot Interpretation

Tags: statistics, regression

I would like to know if the interpretation I'm giving for this residual plot is right.

First, this is the scatterplot.

[image]

The correlation coefficient is 0.61735

The residual plot is:

[image]

The interpretation I gave:

This graph looks good because you don't see many variations and there are no worrisome patterns. There appear to be no difficulties with the model or the data. Therefore, the use of linear regression is reasonable.

Comment: Your residual plot looks more dispersed on the right (though difficult to tell with overlapping points). If so, you may be looking at heteroscedastic residuals

Comment: You might get a better answer to this on stats.stackexchange.com .